# Cassandra Installation

Tags: cassandra

```
ERROR [MemtableFlushWriter:1] 2019-11-05 19:23:08,691 LogReplicaSet.java:94 - Failed to create log replica C:\apache-cassandra-3.11.5\data\data\system\local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/C:\apache-cassandra-3.11.5\data\data\system\local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377\md_txn_flush_99189c20-ffd3-11e9-b69e-0752c2cde782.log
org.apache.cassandra.io.FSReadError: java.io.IOException: Invalid folder descriptor trying to create log replica C:\apache-cassandra-3.11.5\data\data\system\local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LogReplica.create(LogReplica.java:58) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LogReplicaSet.maybeCreateReplica(LogReplicaSet.java:86) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LogFile.makeRecord(LogFile.java:311) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LogFile.add(LogFile.java:283) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LogTransaction.trackNew(LogTransaction.java:139) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LifecycleTransaction.trackNew(LifecycleTransaction.java:528) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter.<init>(BigTableWriter.java:81) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigFormat$WriterFactory.open(BigFormat.java:92) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableWriter.create(SSTableWriter.java:102) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SimpleSSTableMultiWriter.create(SimpleSSTableMultiWriter.java:119) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.AbstractCompactionStrategy.createSSTableMultiWriter(AbstractCompactionStrategy.java:588) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionStrategyManager.createSSTableMultiWriter(CompactionStrategyManager.java:1027) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createSSTableMultiWriter(ColumnFamilyStore.java:532) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.createFlushWriter(Memtable.java:504) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.<init>(Memtable.java:443) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.<init>(Memtable.java:420) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable.createFlushRunnables(Memtable.java:307) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable.flushRunnables(Memtable.java:298) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore$Flush.flushMemtable(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1153) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore$Flush.run(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1118) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_191]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_191]
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:84) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid folder descriptor trying to create log replica C:\apache-cassandra-3.11.5\data\data\system\local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377
        ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Future reference - posting an unformatted error log is a terrible way to get someone to help you.  Start by asking an actual question, and then post only the relevant sections of the log.

Comment: Not a solution yet. I encounter the exact same problem too. However, 3.11.4 works out of the box on Windows 10 for me with everything the same (Java, Python, OS, Filesystem)

Answer (score 7):

Rolling back to version 3.11.4 fixed this issue. Check if you have edited the environment variable of CASSANDRA_HOME to point to version 3.11.4.

Comment: Thanks, 
I had to do the same -- not only roll back, to 3.11.4, but also remember to change the CASSANDRA_HOME back to 3.11.4 as well.

Comment: I did run cassandra on linux, but used CQLSSTableWriter to create sstables on my windows development machine. Downgrading to 3.11.4 on windows did the job.

Answer (score 3):

Try rolling your version back to 3.11.4.  As indicated in [CASSANDRA-15426](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-15426), this should help to get around this issue until a fix is released.

Comment: Rolling back to 3.11.4 doesn't help in my case.

Answer (score 1):

This may have been a permission issue on Windows

1) Open Windows Power Shell
2) run the following command 
       **powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted**

3) Open Windows Command Prompt and execute cassandra.bat

Comment: I tested the above with the version apache-cassandra-3.11.4 and working good for me

Comment: This also worked for me with apache-cassandra-3.11.4

Answer (score 0):

Based off of your pasting, as hard as that was to try to read, I believe your problem is that either you have a permissions issue or a directory/folder doesn't exist that Cassandra is trying to write to:

```
Failed to create log replica C:\apache-cassandra-3.11.5\data\data\system\local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/C:\apache-cassandra-3.11.5\data\data\system\local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377\md_txn_flush_99189c20-ffd3-11e9-b69e-0752c2cde782.log org.apache.cassandra.io.FSReadError: java.io.IOException: Invalid folder descriptor trying to create log replica C:\apache-cassandra-3.11.5\data\data\system\local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377 at
```

So you need to check out: 
C:\apache-cassandra-3.11.5\data\data\system\local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377

See if that directory exists, and whether it is writable (not required to be Administrator or something in that nature). I'm not much of a "windows" guy, so the diagnosis of the issue will fall on your shoulders a bit.

Hope that helps to get things started.

-Jim

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link of cassandra Jira issues regarding this
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-15426

Comment: This is good info to have, but can you explain how this answers the question?

Comment: the issue  has been acknowledged here and if any fix is available , it can be tracked

Answer (score -1):

Here are few things I did to resolve this issue reported by OP:

1. Downgraded the cassandra version to 3.11.4 ( I am using python 2.7 and 
   apacheThrift 0.13)
2. Change CASSANDRA_HOME to updated folder name
3. Open the cmd line as admin  and  Start the cassandra.bat