# Cassandra starting issue : CassandraDaemon

Tags: java, python, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am getting below error while starting my cassandra setup in my machine windows 10.

```
>>cassandra.bat -f
WARNING! Powershell script execution unavailable.
Please use 'powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted'
on this user-account to run cassandra with fully featured
functionality on this platform.
Starting with legacy startup options
Starting Cassandra Server
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon
```

Find below more details :

```
apache-cassandra-3.11.4

java version "1.8.0_45"

Python 3.8.1
```

I have added CASSANDRA_HOME as well in the environment variable.

I tried all possible solution got it from google/stackoverflow but nothing worked.
Previously i was using 3.11.5 but got some error so i got to know that i should use 3.11.4 so i am using it but even this version not working. Find the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58712872/cassandra-installation) for the same.

Please help

Comment: have you done `powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` as described in message?

Comment: Thanks for reply @AlexOtt   I did not understand you. Could you please tell me more on this ?

Comment: the warning says: "Please use 'powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted'" - > have you done it?

Comment: Thankyou so much @AlexOtt its working fine now after setting execution policy to Unrestricted..